# How to use DBUtils in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have the following code:

```
from DBUtils.PooledDB import PooledDB
import pgdb
pool = PooledDB(creator=MySQLdb,
            mincached=1,
            maxcached=20,
            host='127.0.0.1',
            port=3306,
            user='root',
            passwd='XXX',
            db='test')
```

but it can't find the `MySQLdb` module. Is it possible for Python 3 to install MySQLdb? If not, how should can change code to initialize the pool?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `import MySQLdb` in your code, python won't know *MySQLdb* unless you actually import it, *PooledDB* uses the creator directly:

```
creator: either an arbitrary function returning new DB-API 2
        connection objects or a DB-API 2 compliant database module
```

but even with that change it won't work as  MySQLdb does not have a python3 version, you can however you the python [mysql.connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

Answer (score 0):

[PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL) community maintains most of relevant MySQL adapters these days. It includes, [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) which is Python 3 compatible fork of [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) (`MySQLdb`) and pure Python [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL). It's safe to treat mysqlclient as a drop-in replacement for MySQL-python. It's taking over anyway, see [this long thread](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/44).

Thus your code should work as-is after your `pip install mysqlclient`. With PyMySQL it also should work.